# S-pen SDK Compatibility

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab, s-pen

Has anyone seen the S-pens SDK in the Play Store or galaxy apps store? What exactly is it for and even if I'm not developing any kind of modifications to the S-pen feature of Samsung phones can I download the app to enable an S-pen to be used with my phone?
My phone is a Galaxy A5 (2015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your [device](http://www.devicemanuals.eu/samsung-galaxy-a5/1770/) does not have S Pen feature
- [S Pen SDK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.sdk.spen30) app on Play Store is for

> This is the downloadable library for the Pen package, which is a part of the Samsung Mobile SDK. With the library installed, your application regarding SPen is able to use the **latest Pen package features.**

( Emphasis supplied)

- So, **no**, you can't download the app and expect to have S pen enabled on your device, since it doesn't have S pen to start with. Quick search on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series/general/list-custom-roms-galaxy-a5-t3211325) didn't show any mod / custom ROM which has S pen feature
- [S pen SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-3-Tutorial) that can be downloaded from OEM is for *developers* to develop applications using S Pen